# Apache config rewrite: "Unable to execute .. No such file or directory"

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

I've been moving some rewrites from .htaccess to our vhost_ssl.conf file. Most are working fine, except ones that utilize our ecommerce platform.

We use Miva Merchant as our ecommerce platform, which uses its own handler for .mvc files. When I do a rewrite to a .mvc file, Apache (or nginx or something) complains...

```
AddType application/x-miva-compiled .mvc
Action application/x-miva-compiled /cgi-bin/mivavm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/t3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) /mm5/merchant.mvc
```

Result in browser when I visit example.com/t3/:

> Unable to execute 't3/': No such file or directory

Rewrites to "normal" files like .htm or .php work just fine. I have a limited understanding of these sorts of things, but it *seems* to me that the server doesn't understand what to do with the .mvc destination file..? Any suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT: Just wanted to point out that direct visits to .mvc files work fine, so the server does understand what to do. It seems like something about the rewrite confuses things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be that my rewrites needed the `PT` (passthrough) flag added, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/t3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) /mm5/merchant.mvc [PT]
```

There was a ScriptAlias on our cgi-bin directory, which made the the `PT` flag necessary. The `PT` flag is implied in the .htaccess file but not in vhost. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt for details.